# Issue with Intersect method

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a piece of VBA code for Excel Macros which prevents users to input text in the Russian language and it works, however, it throws out an error when copying/pasting a number of cells. I think that I have to limit what Intersect applies to but not sure what is the right way to do so.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Intersect(Target.Cells, [A1:H1000]) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
   If LCase(Target.Cells) Like "*[а-я]*" Then
        With Application
            .EnableEvents = False: .Undo: .EnableEvents = True
             MsgBox "Please use latin letters only"
       End With
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: No - the problem is `LCase(Target.Cells) Like "*[а-я]*" Then`. If `Target` is multiple cells, the comparison will fail. You have to iterate over each cell in `Target`. Note - the `Cells` in `Target.Cells` is redundant.

Comment: which line throws what error?

Comment: What does the error say? Which line throws it?

Comment: You can replace `Intersect(Target.Cells, [A1:H1000])` with `Intersect(Target, [A1:H1000])`. `Target` is already a range object.

Comment: 3rd line gives an error. This one: If LCase(Target.Cells) Like "*[а-я]*" Then

Comment: When you copy/paste a number of cells, then `Target` is a multi-cell range. You can't call `LCase` on a multi-cell range, or use the `Like` operator on a multi-cell range (more detail to my original comment).